# Cómo definir correctamente una variable de sesión dentro de un select

Tags: php, mysql

En un archivo cualquiera.php creo una variable de sesión:

```
$_SESSION['lote'] = $lote; // $lote es integer
```

En otro archivo otro.php, trato de utilizar esa variable de sesión:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tabla WHERE periodo = $periodo AND lote = $_SESSION['lote']";
```

Pero en la línea del Delete obtengo: *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in proceso.php on line 359*

Funciona si asigno de esta manera:

```
$lote2 = $_SESSION['lote']";
$sql = "DELETE FROM tabla WHERE periodo = $periodo AND lote = $lote2";
```

He cambiado las comillas por comillas dobles y muestra el mismo error.
Cuál es mi error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error está en esta línea:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tabla WHERE periodo = $periodo AND lote = $_SESSION['lote']";
```

Cuando PHP trata de interpretar esta línea, llega a `$_SESSION` y trata de volcar su contenido dentro de la cadena. Como `$_SESSION` es un array, aparece el error. Debes "escapar" la expresión completa `$_SESSION['lote']` para que PHP la interprete correctamente. Se hace encerrándola en llaves `{}`:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tabla WHERE periodo = $periodo AND lote = {$_SESSION['lote']}";
```

Puedes comprobarlo haciendo `echo $sql;`.